# How to fix show column view by total document for remaining document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a view named "Software". In this view I show Software name, status, tagno, and total document. I want to calculate total documents that using each software. On my status column I'm using below formula:

```
@If(Form = "MasterFile";"Total License"; "In use")
```

I have two form which is "Computer" where information of software at. Another one is "MasterFile" form where create master file for each software. The information included in master file is Type, Description, and No of License.
For Example, I have one master file with type "Software", Description is "Adobe Photoshop 4.0", and No of License is "2". I also enable total in column properties. My Total column formula as below with output for Total column:

```
@If(Form = "MasterFile"; @Text(NoLicense);"1")
```

[image: sw]

So what I want to achieve is, I have No of license, so when there is used software in document for the software, I will delete no of license and show remaining only.

The total license is no of license, and In use is document with used software. My problem now, the total is additional of total license and In use.
How can I show total of remaining of document, using `Total License - In Use = Remaining`? Is it possible to do this in column view? Any help I really appreaciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the "In Use" column value to -1. This way you get the remaining number of licenses.

I'd probably create three columns:

1. Total Licenses
2. In Use (In Use as 1)
3. Remaining (Total Licenses / In Use as -1)

[image]

Comment: Hi Knut Herrmann, thanks for your answer. I try change "In Use" to -1, but it change "In Use" name to "-1".

Comment: I added the Formula for the Column Remaining. Make sure you have number and not text values.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula at the end of your question gives you the answer - `Total License - In Use`. For `MasterFile` form, the column value should be `TotalValue`. For `In Use` it should be `-1`.

Comment: Hi Paul Stephen Withers, thank you for your answer. What do you mean for MasterFile form, I need to change column value to TotalValue?

Comment: Sorry, @Text(NoLicense)